# undefined variable and invalid supplied argument in a foreach php include inside

Tags: php, foreach

Having this notice:

> Notice: Undefined variable: alumnos in K:\desWebServ\PHP\Examen1A\index.php on line 17
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in K:\desWebServ\PHP\Examen1A\index.php on line 17

apellidos   nombre

accessbd:

```
    <?php
    function obtenerConexion(){
    $dsn = "oci:dbname=//solaris.fleming.as:1521/orclsol;charset=AL32UTF8";
    $usuario = "daim14";
    $password = "daim14";
    try {
        $gbd = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $password,
                array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));

        return $gbd;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "<p>Error: No puede conectarse con la base de datos.</p>\n";
        print "<p>Error: ".$e->getMessage()."</p>\n";
        exit();
    }
    }

    function leerAlumnos(){
    $db = obtenerConexion();
    $consulta = "SELECT APE1, APE2, NOMBRE, NIF
                 FROM RODRIFM.aga_alumnos
                 ORDER BY NOMBRE ASC;";
    $resultado = $db->query($consulta);
    $alumno = $resultado->fetchAll();
    return $alumno;
    }
```

and the index:

```
<?php
require 'accesobd.php';
?>
<html>
<head>

 lista de alumnos
</head>
<body>
    <h1>alumnos matriculados</h1>
  <div id="central">
  <center>
   <table>
    <tr>
  <th >apellidos </th><th>nombre</th><th></th></tr>
 <?php 
    foreach($alumnos as $alumno){
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$alumno['APE1']."</td>";
   echo"<td>".$alumno['APE2']."</td>";
     echo"<td>".$alumno['NOMBRE']."</td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   }

  ?>
 </table>
</BODY>
</html>
```

the error is in the `foreach` of the index, thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$alumnos` variable is not defined, not filled with expected content. Just try with:

```
$alumnos = leerAlumnos();

foreach ($alumnos as $alumno) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: if i do that i get this error Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in K:\desWebServ\PHP\Examen1A\accesobd.php on line 24

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function `leerAlumnos()` in your index. Only then will you get the value of `$alumnos`
something like:
`$alumnos=leerAlumnos();`

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in K:\desWebServ\PHP\Examen1A\accesobd.php on line 24

Comment: @Lord Calo means your query is failing. `$resultado = $db->query($consulta);` is not giving the desired result. check the query.